# Como puedo insertar en sql , donde un campo no sea repetido

Tags: sql

Actualmente tengo una tabla llamada Reserva, el cual tiene

Codigo char
Fecha date
Hora int
Cliente varchar

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, que comando de texto puedo usar, para decirle al programa, por ejemplo supongamos que tengo esto dentro de mi base de datos.

(R01 - '2022-06-10',6,'Juan')

Entonces, si fecha existe, no puedo colocar dentro del campo Hora, otra vez el 6, pero si pongo otro numero diferente, ahi si puedo insertar, esa es mi duda. ¿Que comando de texto, uso?

Answer (score 1):

Sencillo, usa un stored procedure.

Esta sintaxis es en T-SQL, varía un poco para MySQL y PostgreSQL, pero la idea sigue siendo la misma.

1. Supongamos tenemos la siguiente tabla:

```
create table prueba(codigo char, fecha date, hora int, cliente varchar(22))


insert into prueba values('c', '08-15-2021', 5, 'luis')
```

| codigo | fecha | hora | cliente |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c | 2021-08-15 | 5 | carlos |

2. Luego, tenemos que crear nuestro procedimiento almacenado.

```sql
create procedure insertar(@fecha date, @hora int) as 
begin 

  if exists (select 1 from prueba where fecha = @fecha and hora = @hora) begin
  select 'ya existe la hora en la fecha' problema
  end
  
  else begin  
  update prueba set hora = @hora
  end 
  

end
```

3. Lo probamos finalmente.

##### 3.1. Cuando existe la hora en la fecha

```sql
exec insertar '08-15-2021', 5
```

El output sería más o menos así:

| problema |
| --- |
| ya existe la hora en la fecha |

##### 3.2. Cuando no existe la hora en la fecha

```sql
1 rows affected
```

---

> Te dejo el [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=61567cd1851e82f943c698c804995a45)